# Python - looping through rows and concating rows until a certain value is encountered

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting myself very confused over a problem I am encountering with a short python script I am trying to put together. I am trying to iterate through a dataframe, appending rows to a new dataframe, until a certain value is encountered.

```
import pandas as pd


#this function will take a raw AGS file (saved as a CSV) and convert to a
#dataframe.
#it will take the AGS CSV and print the top 5 header lines  
def AGS_raw(file_loc):
    raw_df = pd.read_csv(file_loc)
    #print(raw_df.head())
    return raw_df
    
import_df = AGS_raw('test.csv')

def AGS_snip(raw_df):
    for i in raw_df.iterrows():
        df_new_row = pd.DataFrame(i)
        cut_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_df)
        if "**PROJ" == True:
            cut_df = cut_df.concat([cut_df,df_new_row],ignore_index=True, sort=False)
        elif "**ABBR" == True:
            break
        print(raw_df)
        return cut_df
```

I don't need to get into specifics, but the values (**PROJ and **ABBR) in this data occur as single cells as the top of tables. So I want to loop row-wise through the data, appending rows until **ABBR is encountered.

When I call `AGS_snip(import_df)`, nothing happens. Previous incarnations just spat out the whole df, and I'm just confused over the logic of the loops. Any assistance much appreciated.

EDIT: raw text of the CSV

```
**PROJ,
1,32
1,76
32,56
,
**ABBR,
1,32
1,76
32,56
```

The test CSV looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you want to get a single dataframe for each table in the AGS CSV file? Can you post some of the raw text of the CSV file, and all the table headers you want to extract dataframes for?

Comment: @Aeronautix - that's exactly what I want to do, I'm just struggling with how to set up the loops to do so.

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked, or if you need more help in the parsing behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that "nothing happens" is likely b/c of the conditions you're using in `if` and `elif`.

Neither `"**PROJ" == True` nor `"**ABBR" == True` will ever be `True` because neither `"**PROJ"` nor `"**ABBR"` are equal to `True`. Your code is equivalent to:

```py
def AGS_snip(raw_df):
    for i in raw_df.iterrows():
        df_new_row = pd.DataFrame(i)
        cut_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_df)
        if False:
            cut_df = cut_df.concat([cut_df,df_new_row],ignore_index=True, sort=False)
        elif False:
            break
        print(raw_df)
        return cut_df
```

Which is the same as:

```py
def AGS_snip(raw_df):
    for i in raw_df.iterrows():
        df_new_row = pd.DataFrame(i)
        cut_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_df)
        print(raw_df)
        return cut_df
```

You also always `return` from inside the loop and `df_new_row` isn't used for anything, so it's equivalent to:

```py
def AGS_snip(raw_df):
    first_row = next(raw_df.iterrows(), None)
    if first_row:
        cut_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_df)
        print(raw_df)
        return cut_df
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, can you suggest a condition that would allow me to select these sub tables within my test file? I've added the raw CSV text to my original question.

Comment: I'd say that "this question about loops" has been answered and suggest you ask a new one, e.g.: "How do I split a CSV, concatenated together from multiple CSVs, back into multiple files?". [To ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), be sure to include that explicit example, your code attempt, and your best understanding as to why it doesn't do what you think it should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to parse your CSV file into multiple separate dataframes based on a row condition. Each dataframe is stored in a Python dictionary, with titles as keys and dataframes as values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ags.csv', header=None)

# Drop rows which consist of all NaN (Not a Number) / missing values.
# Reset index order from 0 to the end of dataframe.
df = df.dropna(axis='rows', how='all').reset_index(drop=True)

# Grab indices of rows beginning with "**", and append an "end" index.
idx = df.index[df[0].str.startswith('**')].append(pd.Index([len(df)]))

# Dictionary of { dataframe titles : dataframes }.
dfs = {}
for k in range(len(idx) - 1):
    table_name = df.iloc[idx[k],0]
    dfs[table_name] = df.iloc[idx[k]+1:idx[k+1]].reset_index(drop=True)

# Print the titles and tables.
for k,v in dfs.items():
    print(k)
    print(v)
# **PROJ
#     0     1
# 0   1  32.0
# 1   1  76.0
# 2  32  56.0
# **ABBR
#     0     1
# 0   1  32.0
# 1   1  76.0
# 2  32  56.0

# Access each dataframe by indexing the dictionary "dfs", for example:
print(dfs['**ABBR'])
#     0     1
# 0   1  32.0
# 1   1  76.0
# 2  32  56.0

# You can rename column names with for example this code:
dfs['**PROJ'].set_axis(['data1', 'data2'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
print(dfs['**PROJ'])
#   data1  data2
# 0     1   32.0
# 1     1   76.0
# 2    32   56.0
```